# Cookies in loopj for android

Tags: android, cookies

How do I get cookies using loopj? I know how to set it, but I can`t get it. http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are creating and using your own `PersistentCookieStore` instance as follows:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this)
httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Then you can simply use the `cookieStore` instance you created above.

Otherwise, with the latest [android-async-http from github](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http), you can do the following:

```
HttpContext httpContext = httpClient.getHttpContext();
CookieStore cookieStore = (CookieStore) httpContext.getAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE);
```

Once you have the `cookieStore` instance, you can [follow the docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) to access the cookies.

Comment: Hehe, clearly the top guy qualified to answer the question. :D

Comment: Brilliant answer. How did I miss that?

Comment: Note, tho, that PersistentCookieStore is misspelled in the code above. :-)  My copy and paste failed me for 5 full minutes.