# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp and request cookies

Tags: android, android-async-http

Regarding to LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp [examples](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) I make a get request like this:

```
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://example.com/mypage/", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            text.append(response);
        }
    });
```

I also add cookies:

```
    PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
    client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
    BasicClientCookie newCookie = new BasicClientCookie("id", 17882);
    myCookieStore.addCookie(newCookie);
```

But while making a GET request how can I send my cookies inside the request object ?

Regarding to [documentation](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html) client has these method signatures:

```
 void   get(Context context, String url, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) 
 void   get(Context context, String url, Header[] headers, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) 
 void   get(Context context, String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) 
 void   get(String url, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) 
 void   get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
```

I would be happy if you can give an example that sends persistent cookies inside the GET request.

Comment: you are adding cookies already when you set client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore). Just make sure you add them before client.get()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating your own `PersistentCookieStore` instance, Simply use the `myCookieStore` instance you created. Like @robotoaster says add it before get().

OR

Do this

```
HttpContext httpContext = httpClient.getHttpContext();
CookieStore cookieStore = (CookieStore) httpContext.getAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE);
```

Then follow instructions at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html .

Source: [Cookies in loopj for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712221/cookies-in-loopj-for-android) 
(Straight from loopj)